# C# DataSet DataTableAdapter Query Builder SQL options

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, linq-to-dataset

I have a Windows Form C# project running in Visual Studio 2013. In this project, I created a DataSet and a few DataTableAdapter and DataTables.

When you right click on a DataTableAdapter -> Configure, you get a "Query Builder" option where you can build a query for your database (in my case, an ODBC connection).

Here is my problem. The query I am allowed to build appears very limited in terms of the types of the methods that are available to me. For example, I can't seem to use TOP or LIMIT:

```
Select Id, RecordTime, Value from tbl ORDER BY RecordTime LIMIT(1)
```

or

```
Select DISTINCT TOP (1) Id, RecordTime, Value from tbl
```

The Above 2 queries will generate an error when I try to save it. But if I remove the TOP and LIMIT clauses, I get no errors.

Quite simply what I am trying to achieve is to get only the 1st row or the last row. I can't seem to find an easy way to do that here.

Comment: If you're only getting the TOP 1 then Distinct is irrelevant in SQL Query

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am a bit new to SQL in general as well. Could you advice how you could retrieve just the 1st row?